# Java: is it possible to store raw data in source file?

Tags: java, floating-point

OK, I know this is a bit of a weird question:

I'm writing this piece of java code and need to load raw data (approx 130000 floating points):

This data never changes, and since I don't want to write different loading methods for PC and Android, I was thinking of embedding it into the source file as a `float[]`.

Too bad, there seems to be a limit of 65535 entries; is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: Why not store that data in a file in the classpath?

Comment: because android won't let me load anything from there, I'd have to write a different loading method that load the file from the assets

Comment: "android won't let me load anything from there" <-- uhwhat? There isn't `.getResourceAsStream()` in Android?

Comment: there is, but as far as i know it never loads anything, just throws an exception

Comment: This is because you don't use it correctly; it works. Show some code where it fails for you

Comment: MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("myFile.raw"); returns the Stream on PC, but null on android

Comment: Then the problem is with the packaging on android; look at where the file is located in the jar you generate vs where you expect it to be.

Comment: I suggest you to fix your real problem and do not try to create a nasty workaround for it.

Comment: now i feel like an idiot, I just had to use an absolute path instead of relative.

Answer (score 2):

Store that data in a file in the classpath; then read that data as a `ByteBuffer` which you then "convert" to a `FloatBuffer`. Note that the below code assumes big endian:

```
final InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/data");
final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

final byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
int count;

try {
    while ((count = in.read(buf)) != -1)
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
} finally {
    out.close();
    in.close();
}

final FloatBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toByteArray()).asFloatBuffer();
```

You can then `.get()` from the `FloatBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 or 3 arrays to get around the limit, if that was your only problem with that approach.